# Firebase and busboy, do I get the whole file in memory, or?

Tags: firebase, pipe, streaming, google-cloud-functions, busboy

I want to upload rather large files in a node.js/Firebase project. I am trying to understand if Busboy fits my need.

The example in the Busboy documentation ends with

```
req.pipe(busboy);
```

However this does not work in Firebase. It looks like you instead should use

```
busboy.end(req.rawBody);
```

That works for me (at least locally, under `firebase serve`. However there is a difference, perhaps. In the example I mentioned above you have this:

```
if (req.method === 'POST') {
    let busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
      console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ', encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);
      file.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');
      });
```

### I expected to see several outputs from `file.on("data", ...)`, but there is just one line for a 100 MB file. Does this mean that the whole file is kept in memory?

EDIT: The `busboy.end(req.rawBody)` is from https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#multipart_data

Answer (score 1):

The entire request and response for Cloud Functions input and output is kept entirely in memory before being transferred to and from the client.  The maximum payload size for requests and responses is 10MB, as shown in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas).

When working with large files, you should consider uploading to Cloud Functions, then trigger a function from there.

Comment: Thanks Doug. In these case my idea was to stream the file through Busboy with a pipe to Google Cloud Storage. I am very unsure what works how in cases like this. The example in the Busboy documentation looks like you could stream a file that way. Am I misunderstanding that example? Or is it just that this does not work with Firebase yet?

Comment: As I said, Cloud Functions doesn't actually stream the input. It is all in memory the moment the function is invoked. Streaming doesn't scale in the way that Cloud Functions requires. You can stream from Cloud Storage using its node API, however.

Comment: This was just another try to find a way to upload big files to GCS. Please see my other question here where you also answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56237102/using-websocket-stream-to-upload-file-to-cloud-storage-with-firebase-node-js?noredirect=1#comment99103262_56237102