# Using websocket-stream to upload file to Cloud Storage with Firebase Node.js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, websocket, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am struggling with finding a good way to upload bigger files from the web browser to Google Cloud Storage in a Firebase project. Now I want to try the [websocket-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket-stream) package. However I do not understand how to set it up in Firebase. Is it possible?

From the documentation you should do this in `Node.js`:

```
var websocket = require('websocket-stream')
var wss = websocket.createServer({server: someHTTPServer}, handle)
```

Where this is assumed:

```
var someHTTPServer = http.createServer();
```

How do I get `someHTTPServer` when I use Firebase?

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to accomplish here? You can't set up an arbitrary websocket server using Firebase products.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks, that is good to know. I want to stream somewhat bigger files from a web browser (Chrome) to Google Cloud Storage. I just tried using `getSignedUrl`, but that fails because streaming is not implemented in "PUT" for the `fetch` Javascript function. I mean that is how I understand it, see ... Hm, my question about that seems to have been deleted from here. I asked a question about it just a few days ago.

Comment: @DougStevenson, any way to do that upload with just Firebase (using Node.js) would be fine for me, but I do not understand how to do it. I looked at it a year ago and did not understand. I thought that it would be easier now.

Comment: @DougStevenson Hm, my question about `getSignedUrl` was not deleted, but did not show up for some reason. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206972/getsignedurl-how-to-upload-large-files-from-a-web-browser